# If $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = 1$, then find a value for $\sin^3(x) + \cos^3(x)$ and $\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am able to find an expression for both but not a value. Can someone please help me solve this question?

Comment: If $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ = 1 what does that tell you about x?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Squaring the given equation  you get $2\sin x \cos x=0$ or $\sin (2x)=0$. Can you write down all $x$ for which this is true?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$ always holds. Noting $\sin(x) = y$, this gives us
\begin{align*}
y \pm \sqrt{1-y^2} =& 1 \\
\pm \sqrt{1-y^2} =& 1-y \\
1-y^2 =& 1 - 2y + y^2 \\
2y^2-2y =& 0 \\
y(y-1) =& 0
\end{align*}
Hence, either $\sin(x) = 1$ and $\cos(x) = 0$ or $\cos(x) = 1$ and $\sin(x) = 0$. Both cases yield $\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x) = 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$$

$$ (\sin(x) + \cos(x))^2 =1 =  1 + 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$$

$$\implies sin(x)\cos(x) = 0$$